# Cannot install TypeScript globally

Tags: typescript, npm-install

I've been using this node command:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

However, the downloaded  package always goes to `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\tsserver`.

When `tsc -v` is called outside Git directory, it prints the following message:

> `'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your npm path is not correctly defined

Run this:

```
npm config get prefix
```

The default is C:\usr\local, which means that npm will symlink binaries into C:\usr\local\bin , which should already be on your PATH.

So run :

```
npm config set prefix C:\Usr\local
```

Finnaly, If NPM is not in your path run this :

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Usr\local
```

Comment: can you also include answer for Mac? tks !

Answer (score 2):

Try the below command on Unix prompt:

```
sudo npm install -g typescript
```